# Unix Command - Find files recursively having a string and then print the count of it's occurrences against each file

Tags: unix

Need to find all files having a particular string and then the count of those occurrences. Should print something like this

xyz/abc.txt 25
xyz/tt1/xyz.txt 35

Comment: What is the search string in this case, what did you try and why didn't you use `{}` formatting your question?

Answer (score 0):

Combine `sort` and `uniq -c` like this:

```
/bin/ls -c1 *<STRING>* | sort | uniq -c
```

or use this to recurse into sub-directories:

```
find . -type f -name "*<STRING>*" -print | sort | uniq -c
```

The `sort` is required since `uniq -c` collapses identical adjacent lines into one, and the `-c` option adds the number of collapsed lines.